# C# no implicit fall through in switch statement

Tags: c#, c++, switch-statement

I am from C++ background. I recently wrote a program that gives information about how many notes of particular Rs. are needed when it asks for specific amount.
Without telling further following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int main()
{
    int amount,notes,choice;
    cout<<"Enter the amount: ";
    cin>>amount;
    cout<<"Enter the value of note from which you want to start: ";
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 100:
            notes=amount/100;
            cout<<"no of 100 rupees notes = "<<notes<<'\n';
            amount=amount%100;
        case 50:
            notes=amount/50;
            cout<<"no of 50 rupees notes = "<<notes<<'\n';
            amount=amount%50;
        case 20:
            notes=amount/20;
            cout<<"no of 20 rupees notes = "<<notes<<'\n';
            amount=amount%20;
        case 10:
            notes=amount/10;
            cout<<"no of 10 rupees notes = "<<notes<<'\n';
            amount=amount%10;
        case 5:
            notes=amount/5;
            cout<<"no of 5 rupees notes = "<<notes<<'\n';   
            amount=amount%5;
        case 2:
            notes=amount/2;
            cout<<"no of 2 rupees notes = "<<notes<<'\n';
            amount=amount%2;
        case 1:
            notes=amount/1;
            cout<<"no of 1 rupees notes = "<<notes<<'\n';
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Enter only valid values";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now my question is that how can I write this program in C#? In C# there is no implicit fall through cases but in this program implicit fall through cases is required. Then which are the ways I can do this program in C#? 
Please help me.

Comment: Are you constrained to using a `switch` statement in your solution?

Comment: fall through is one of the dumbest things I have ever seen in 30+ years of IT and a sure sign of bad programming style, imnsho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dennis_E has the easiest change for you but you can avoid goto and much repetition by using a loop construct :)

For example:

```
using System;

namespace CurrencyNotes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int amount;
            int choice;

            Console.Write("Enter the amount: ");
            amount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the value of note from which you want to start: ");
            choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            CountNotes(amount, choice);
        }

        static void CountNotes(int amount, int choice)
        {
            int notes = 0;
            int[] choices = { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };

            // Find starting choice
            int i = 0;
            while (choice < choices[i])
                ++i;

            // Output number of notes for each suitable choice
            while (amount > 0)
            {
                notes = amount / choices[i];
                if (notes > 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("no. of {0} rupees notes = {1}", choices[i], notes);
                amount %= choices[i];
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for it is that implicit fall through is a cause for subtle bugs, when you forget to add `break;` If you need to fall through, you can use goto:

```
case 100:
    notes=amount/100;
    cout<<"no of 100 rupees notes = "<<notes<<'\n';
    amount=amount%100;
    goto case 50;
```

Comment: any other way that doesn't involve use of goto because use of goto leads to unstructured code &  hard to understand code

Comment: The same could be said for all the other jump statements. `goto` has its uses in some cases. In the C# documentation, this is the recommended way of doing fall through.

Comment: @meet I fail to see how in this case. Your reluctance to use `goto` appears to be from the hate surrounding it, not experience. `goto` is sometimes a perfectly valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would be inclined to go with an entirely different approach. By means of an array instead of a switch.

Something akin to:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int[] notes = new int[] { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };
            int amount = 0;

            amount = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
            foreach (int i in notes) {
                Console.WriteLine (amount / i);
                amount = amount % i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```